# SELECT command denied to user on database that doesn't exist

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Been bothered with this for awhile now and i think it might be how i have the joins set up.

I have two tables. Ones is called info which contains all of a users contact information. My second table called numbers has all the phonenumbers for different users. They are related by the primary id of info to the info_id of phonenumbers. I want them to join based on this relationship and I want all the phonenumbers under phonenumbers to join into the single phonenumbers column in info. The current join i am using is this.

```
SELECT phonenumbers p, info i FROM i.phonenumbers 
INNER JOIN p.workphone 
ON i.PID=p.info_id 
INNER JOIN p.homephone 
ON i.PID=p.info_id 
INNER JOIN p.mobilephone 
ON  i.PID=p.info_id
```

all i get is the SELECT comman is deneied to user on database workphone that isnt evena  database.

table info: 
PID,
firstname,
lastname,
address,
email,
phonenumbers,

table phonenumbers: 
PID,
workphone,
homephone,
mobilephone,
info_id,

The syntax for a join would be nice. All the tutorials just give examples and not an explanation of what the different pieces are.

Comment: What are you using to connect to your database?  Do you have the proper permissions to select from the tables on that server?

Comment: Do you understand the `JOIN`s you are doing?

Comment: Even without the messed up aliases, that doesn't look right. Some idea of the structures of the tables involved, and the desired result would be a boon.

Comment: Well your real problem is you seem to need a union given the total unnormalised design you have.

Comment: No don't get it, give us some example data, you've done something really weird there, or your columns names are misleading at best.

Answer (score 1):

JOIN syntax is

```
TYPE_OF_JOIN database.table ON field = field
```

Since you have

```
JOIN p.workphone ON i.PID = p.info_id
```

You're actually telling the DB to look for a database named `p`, which contains a table `workphone`.

Doesn't matter that you've created an alias `p` up in your SELECT fields list. That's a field alias, and they NOT the same as a table alias.